# How to change an intent from a settings activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

m trying to change the intent of a button in the main activity from a settings activity how can i do that?

this what i,m trying to do but i dont know how to complete it

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

RadioButton rdpc, rdps, rdxb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    rdpc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdpc);
    rdps = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdps);
    rdxb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdxb);


}

public class changedefactivity extends MainActivity{

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML file, add an onClick attribute to your RadioButtons. Pass in a function such as "onRadioButtonClicked".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Then, in the activity that hosts the layout, create a method that handles the click event for your radio buttons:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

In the switch statement, you can add your intents using the following:

```
Intent radioIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
//Pass any extras in
startActivity(radioIntent);
```

---

I'm not quite sure how your code is supposed to be organized. 
For a start, best practices would have your **SettingsActivity** extend **PreferenceActivity** (or **PreferenceFragment** for Android 3.0 and higher):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

From that activity, the user can toggle/set/declare certain settings which can be saved via SharedPreferences, which can be accessed by your app/MainActivity using the PreferenceManager:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String syncConnPref = sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN, "");
```

[Documentation for SettingsActivity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Comment: i mean that i have 3 radiobuttons each of them sets a specfic intent to the main activity so the first radio button makes the main activity start another activity by default

Comment: Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: Never mind what im trying to do is bad practice because i,m trying to call method from another activity which is bad

Comment: If my answer helped to answer your original question, please mark it as an answer

Comment: Also, using Intents is the best practice for communicating through activities.

Comment: And so I can further help you, what do you intend to do with your settings activity?

Comment: my settings activity became useless i only needed it to let the user change the default activity that will open up on app launch but this design is useless and bad practice instead i can use a tabbed activity